# Some basic questions about Routing in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET MVC and have a few questions about routing.

`Print` is a controller, with a `Show` action, that takes a parameter and returns it back as string.

Consider the code

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Print",
          url: "Print/{action}/{id}",
           defaults:  new { controller = "Print", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional });


    }
```

Why do I get a 404 error when I try `host:xxxxx/Print/xxx...`? Shouldn't it take me to the `Show` action?

Also if I set `url:Print`, and try `host:xxxxx/Print` I get the same error. It should take me to the `Show` action.

Similarly if I set `url:Print/{action}/{id}` and try `host:xxxxx/Print/Show` it gives the same error, even though the parameter is optional, and should return blank?

But if I interchange the two routes such that the `Print` route is first in precedence and `Home/Index` in second, I do not get any errors in any cases? `host:xxxxx/Print` shows blank, `host:xxxxx/Print/Show` shows blank and `host:xxxxx/Print/Show/xxx...` returns some value.

Why do I get errors if I set it as the second route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the routes register order to:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Print",
        url: "Print/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Print", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

The routes in the `RegisterRoutes()` are analyzed in order they are added to the `routes`. The `Default` route pattern is universal, therefore the second doesn't work. The MVC trying to find the `Show` action in the `Home` controller and does not finding it. Therefore it report the `404` error.

If look at the `RouteCollection` declaration it is inherited from `IList<T>`. So, the routes analyzed in order they added to the routes table.

Any your routes should be added before the `Default` route.

Comment: @Farhan Ullah: For more information see the documentation: [ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)